# Would the universe look any different today if energy/matter had not appeared until some time after spacetime had begun expanding?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang

Why is it necessary for spacetime and energy/matter to begin together at spacetime = 0? Would the universe look any different today if energy/matter had appeared some time after spacetime had begun expanding?

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of the universe and the energy/matter content are not independant. They are linked through the [Friedmann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations). If there was no matter/energy we just get a Minkowski spacetime and this doesn't expand, contract or do back flips.

I suppose in principle you could have a Minkowski universe then wave a wand and have the matter/energy appear so the universe started expanding. I've seen suggestions that the universe might have started this way with the matter/energy being supplied by a vacuum fluctuation. But even leaving aside the magic required, that universe would look just like ours with the zero of time being the moment the matter/energy appeared. So we couldn't tell if this had happened.

**Response to comment:**

I interpreted no energy/matter to mean no dark energy either. If you have dark energy but no other energy/matter then you do indeed get a de Sitter universe that expands exponentially.

However this makes less difference than you might have thought because a de Sitter universe has no Big Bang. This seems odd until you imagine what happens if you reverse the clock. When seen in reverse a de Sitter universe shrinks exponentially, which means it approaches zero size but never gets there even given infinite time. So in both the de Sitter and Minkowski universes there is no Big Bang until you magically create the matter/energy.

Comment: I've been told that a DeSitter universe would expand by default regardless of having no matter. The vacuum energy would cause it.

Comment: @LionelDoolan: I've edited my answer to respond to your comment.